# Add the system default press color to a layout

Tags: android, colors, selector

I have a clickable layout. I want the pressed state to be the same as the system. For example, kitkat has a white background, sony devices has a different one etc..
is there a way to get this default color and set it to my RelativeLayout?
Thanks!